# Intellij plugin, gradle always download LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT of java-compiler-ant-tasks when use localPath

Tags: gradle, intellij-plugin

When I use gradle to build intellij plugin and use localPath config like this:

intellij {
localPath 'D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3'
}

The gradle always download the java-compiler-ant-tasks-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT.jar, not the specific version such as java-compiler-ant-tasks-192.5728.105.jar.

How can let gradle do not download the latest version ? My maven reposity is in my compony network which can not connect the internet, and I can only put specific version like java-compiler-ant-tasks-192.5728.105.jar in my maven repository, because the maven repository only accepte release version.

Thanks